# Slow performance when changing theme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I want ny app more flexible for users and trying make my font sizes scalable. For this i'm  increment "sizes" properties in theme object.

```
const userConfig = useSelector(selectUserConfig)
const userTheme = useMemo(() => getUserTheme(userConfig), [userConfig])
...
const getUserTheme = (userConfig: IUser['config'] = { fontSize: 0, iconSize: 0 }): any => {
  return {
    ...theme,
    components: {
      ...theme.components,
      Icon: {
        ...theme.components.Icon,
        sizes: increaseObjProps(theme.components.Icon.sizes, userConfig.iconSize),
      },
    },
    fontSizes: increaseObjProps(theme.fontSizes, userConfig.fontSize),
  }
}

function increaseObjProps(obj: any, value: number) {
  const newObj: any = {}
  for (const key in obj) {
    newObj[key] = typeof obj[key] === 'number' ? obj[key] + value : obj[key]
  }

  return newObj
}
```

After changing **userConfig.fontSize** app stop user interactions for 4-5 seconds. How can I speed up the theme change in the app?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but you should know that the OS can scale your fonts using accessibilities properties from the OS configuration, so you don't really have to worry about scaling fonts, the OS will do it for you if the user has the that property on.

Comment: Thank you, but we need exactly manual scaling for our users. Font size it's only example.